# I'm making a draggable todo list using UUID, but I would appreciate someone's help in converting it to retrieve data from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, uuid

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DragDropContext, Draggable, Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import uuid from "uuid/v4";

const itemsFromBackend = [
  { id: uuid(), content: "First task" },
  { id: uuid(), content: "Second task" },
  { id: uuid(), content: "Third task" },
  { id: uuid(), content: "Fourth task" },
  { id: uuid(), content: "Fifth task" }
];

const columnsFromBackend = {
  [uuid()]: {
    name: "Requested",
    items: itemsFromBackend
  },
  [uuid()]: {
    name: "To do",
    items: []
  },
  [uuid()]: {
    name: "In Progress",
    items: []
  },
  [uuid()]: {
    name: "Done",
    items: []
  }
};

const onDragEnd = (result, columns, setColumns) => {
  if (!result.destination) return;
  const { source, destination } = result;

  if (source.droppableId !== destination.droppableId) {
    const sourceColumn = columns[source.droppableId];
    const destColumn = columns[destination.droppableId];
    const sourceItems = [...sourceColumn.items];
    const destItems = [...destColumn.items];
    const [removed] = sourceItems.splice(source.index, 1);
    destItems.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);
    setColumns({
      ...columns,
      [source.droppableId]: {
        ...sourceColumn,
        items: sourceItems
      },
      [destination.droppableId]: {
        ...destColumn,
        items: destItems
      }
    });
  } else {
    const column = columns[source.droppableId];
    const copiedItems = [...column.items];
    const [removed] = copiedItems.splice(source.index, 1);
    copiedItems.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);
    setColumns({
      ...columns,
      [source.droppableId]: {
        ...column,
        items: copiedItems
      }
    });
  }
};
```

I don't want to use UUID . So can anyone help me with writing code so that I can fetch itemsFromBackend and columnFromBackend from MongoDB. I want it to be dynamic with the databases .
I was taking reference from https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-leakey-i0ex5?file=/src/App.js:0-1726

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.